# Disable div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the event `onClick=window.location.href = 'some url stored in div`.

`Div` contains images as well as text.

I want to show preview using this `div`, but want clicking disabled on this `div` because it is taking to the specified location.

I tried it like this:

```
("#preview").disabled= true;
("#preview").disabled= 'disabled';
("#preview").children().disabled= true;
("#preview").children().disabled= 'disabled';
```

But none of this is working in `firefox 3.6`. Somebody please help to solve this problem.

Comment: So you've got a "click" handler set up, but you want it to not work -- why not just take away that "onclick" attribute?  None of those things you wrote will work because, well, they're all wrong.  You can't just disable an element like that; it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I want to save the html in db with this inline onclick event. but when I preview it I want it to be disabled. how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable all the div's controls, you can try adding a transparent div on the div to disable, you gonna make it unclickable, also use fadeTo to create a disable appearance.

try this.

```
$('#DisableDiv').fadeTo('slow',.6);
$('#DisableDiv').append('<div style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#preview').unbind('click');
```

Comment: this will not work for an inline-handler.

Answer (score 1):

First, why would you use an *inline event* handler while using a library like jQuery. Do it the unobtrusive way and bind all event handlers with Javascript.

This actually will also help you with your problem, because then you can *unbind* and *rebind* an event handler very easily:

```
function myclick() {
   window.location.href = 'some url';
}

// bind the click event handler
$(function() {
    $('#preview').bind('click', myclick);
});

// unbind the click event handler
$('#preview').unbind('click', myclick);
```

That way, you can add and remove the functionality, but it won't change any visible change to the *div node*. You would also have to add a *style* or *css class* to let an user know that something changed.

Ref.: [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: Actually it is fixed html code in which I'm just replacing a few things. Kind of a template and this html is saved in db. I want all the clicks and this event to be disabled when preview it in a div. but when I actually use it on the site this event should be there. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should be able to simply do:</strike>

```
// Unbind all click events for all elements
("#preview *").unbind("click");
```

The other thing you could do is what modals often do with the background: place a non-clickable div on top of the other content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#preview div").onClick = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#the_div_id *').unbind('click');
```